# Google chrome doesn't show the for loop in detail. I want to see every step

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, for-loop, console

I know It is a silly question to ask but I'm starting new and trying to be a frontend developer. I was playing around with for loops and I wanted to know how chrome process it, so I try to view it on console section of chrome. It shows me that loop has processed 100 steps but It doesn't show it in detail.

I'm attaching the for loop and the screenshot from console. Many thanks in advance.

```
let age = 18;

if (age < 10) {
  console.log("older than 10 years");
} else if (age === 10) {
  console.log("10 years old");
} else if (age > 10 && age < 20) {
  console.log("the age is between 10 and 20");
} else {
  console.log("younger than 10 years");
}

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
   console.log("i")
}
```

Screenshot from the console

[image]

I want to see the results as this: starting from 1 and ending with 99.

Comment: please paste the code snippet instead of an image

Comment: You should do `console.log(i)` , remove the quotes around the i

Comment: Issie is with your loop. 
In your case, you are printing the i which is a string (in double quotes). 
Remove the double quotes from i and then try it.

for(let i =0; i<=100; i++){
 console.log(i);
}

Comment: Thanks, I removed the quotes. And I will paste the code from now on. Sorry, newbie here.

Answer (score 1):

The `(100)` means that there are 100 duplicate log messages, so it just shows one of them along with the count.

If you want to see them all, open the console settings (the gear icon above the console output area) and uncheck "Group similar messages in console". Then you will see 100 lines with the message `i`.

If you intended to see the numbers from 0 to 100 you shouldn't put `i` in quotes. That makes it a string instead of a variable.

Comment: Thank you! I removed the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>
        // age output
        let age = parseInt(prompt("enter"));
        if (age < 10) {
            console.log("younger than 10 years");
        } else if (age === 10) {
            console.log("10 years old");
        } else if (age > 10 && age < 20) {
            console.log("the age is between 10 and 20");
        } else {
            console.log("above than 20 years");
        }

        // loop for 1 to 99
        for (let age = 0; age < 100; age++) {

            console.log(age);
        }
    </script>
```